# read json object in php

Tags: php, json

I have some json object like this:

```
{"g_aaa77":
    {"'title'":"title2",
        "'r_a6cff'":                
            {"name":"name2","price":"2"},
        "'r_7fc7b'":   
            {"name":"name22","price":"22"}
     },
 "g_a36b5":
     {"title":"title1",
         "r_4e122": 
             {"name":"name1","price":"1"},
         "r_155fa":
             {"name":"name11","price":"11"}
     }
}
```

`g_aaa77` and `g_a36b5` are a random string.

Also `r_a6cff`,`r_7fc7b`,`r_4e122`,`r_155fa`

How can I read this json?

Normally is this way:

```
$json = { .. };

$json->g_a36b5->title;
```

But I do not have 'g_a36b5'. it is a random string.

maybe I must convert this json to another or something like this.

can u please tell me how can I read this json?

Comment: Start by json_decoding it

Comment: You can use `json_decode()` then a `foreach` loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of, `json_decode` your json.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Now you'll need to loop through with a foreach, since you still don't know what the keys are:

```
foreach($array AS $key => $subarray) {
    echo $key . ": " . print_r($subarray, true);
}
```

If you don't care about keeping the keys, you can just remove those random strings with `array_values`.

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Now you can still loop through it, or just address an array element directly via numeric key:

```
print_r($array[0]);
echo $array[1]['title']; // title1
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/s2it1